# MySQL select distinct across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have a query that selects all columns from multiple tables, but it's returning multiples of the same values (I only want distinct values).

How can I incorporate something like this? When I try this, it still

```
Select Distinct A.*, B.*, C.*....
```

Does distinct only work when selecting the column names and not all (*) ? In [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) reference it says distinct in reference to column names, not across all of the tables. Is there any way that I can do this?

**edit - I added more info below**

Sorry guys, I just got back onto my computer. Also, I just realized that my query itself is the issue, and Distinct has nothing to do with it.

So, the overall goal of my Query is to do the following

1. Generate a list of friends that a user has
2. Go through the friends and check their activities (posting, adding friends, etc..)
3. Display a list of friends and their activities sorted by date (I guess like a facebook wall kind of deal).

Here are my tables

```
update_id |  update | userid  | timestamp  //updates table

post_id |  post | userid  | timestamp      //posts table

user_1 |   user_2  | status   |  timestamp   //friends table
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT U.* , P.* ,F.* FROM posts AS P 
JOIN updates AS U ON P.userid = U.userid 
JOIN friends AS F ON P.userid = F.user_2 or F.user_1
WHERE P.userid IN (
        select user_1 from friends where user_2 = '1'
        union
        select user_2 from friends where user_1 = '1'
        union
        select userid from org_members where org_id = '1'
        union
        select org_id from org_members where userid = '1'
        ) 
ORDER BY P.timestamp, U.timestamp, F.timestamp limit 30
```

The issue I'm having with this (that I thought was related to distinct), is that if values are found to meet the requirements in, say table Friends, a value for the Posts table will appear too. This means when I'm displaying the output of the SQL statement, it appears as if the Posts value is shown multiple times, when the actual values I'm looking for are also displayed

The output will appear something like this (notice difference between post value in the rows)

```
update_id |  update | userid  | timestamp | post_id |  post | userid  | timestamp | user_1 |   user_2  | status   |  timestamp

     1    | update1 |   1    | 02/01/2013 |    1    |  post1|  1      |  2/02/2013|  1     |   2       |  1       | 01/30/2013
     1    | update1 |   1    | 02/01/2013 |    2    |  post2|  1      |  2/03/2013|  1     |   2       |  1       | 01/30/2013
```

So, as you can see, I thought I was having a distinct issue (because update1 appeared both times), but the query actually just selects all the values regardless. I get the results I'm looking for in the Post table, but all the other values are returned. So, when I display the table in PHP/HTML, the Post value will display, but I also get duplicates of the updates (just for this example)

Comment: How are these tables related?  Sounds like maybe you ought be doing a `UNION`...  Post their schemas.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data you are using and the results you want?  `SELECT DISTINCT` works.  Your expectation of what it does needs to be updated.

Comment: Don't you have some auto_increment there? The question is so vague ...

Comment: [Seems to work](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86f24/1), or is that not what you want?

Comment: Maybe you should show the whole SELECT — the FROM clause with its JOINs (or the FROM clause and WHERE clause if you're not using JOIN).  And some simple data that shows your claimed non-uniqueness — both the input tables and sample data and the output.  Two tables should be enough to illustrate; three would be plenty.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I updated my post above

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated my post, sorry for the lack of detail.

Answer (score 0):

When you select distinct *, you select every row, including the one that makes the record unique.  If you want something better than what you are getting, you have to type the individual column names in your select clause.

Comment: I updated my post above. Can you please take a look at my edit?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
select *
from tableA
union
select * 
from tableB
union
select * 
from tableC
```

This assumes that HHS tables all have the same number of columns and they are of the same data type. This not, you'll have to select specific columns to make it so.

Comment: I apologize for the delay. I was out and just returned. I updated my post above

Comment: The update completely changes the question. You should revert your change, abandon this question, and a new one.

Comment: @Dalius quite so! Edited :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy if you explain a little more what is the connection between the tables you'r querying, because you can use joins, unions (as mentioned above) or even group by's ...

Comment: I updated my post above. Sorry for the lack of info. I was out for a while and just got back on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated post shows one of the JOIN conditions as:

```
JOIN friends AS F ON P.userid = F.user_2 OR F.user_1
```

This is equivalent to:

```
JOIN friends AS F ON (P.userid = F.user_2 OR F.user_1  != 0)
```

and will include many rows that you did not intend to include.
You probably intended:

```
JOIN friends AS F ON (P.userid = F.user_2 OR P.userid = F.user_1)
```